# Add line break in LWC toast message

Tags: lightning-web-components, toast

How can we achieve a new line in an LWC toast message? I tried using `<br>` and `/n` .. but it is not working. It's working in Aura, but not in LWC.

JS-

```
showSuccessToast() {
    var sMsg = 'Salesforce documentation is available in the app.<br/>';
    sMsg += 'Click ? in the upper-right corner.';
    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Record Update',
        message: sMsg,
        variant: 'success',
        mode: 'sticky'
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

[image]

Comment: When you said you tried "/n" did you mean "\n"?

Comment: yes tried that one and <br> tag also..

Comment: Idea exchange
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdkhjUAB/showtoastevent-message-display-in-multiple-line-lwc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try `\n` instead of `/n`. That aside, it is [documented that there are some limitations between the Aura and LWC versions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_map_aura_lwc_components); use Aura if you definitely need this today. You can use an Aura wrapper and dispatch an event from your LWC to Aura, then have Aura use the lightning:notificationsLibrary module to show your message from there.

Comment: \n i tried not working.

Comment: @hellraizer Like I said, there's not exactly feature parity between LWC and Aura. Consider using Aura instead.

Comment: Can you un-accept this answer @hellraizer?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I've resolved it with putting `'\n'` in my text and also setting `lightning-formatted-text` tag that will show my text.
Here is example how I've achieved it:

In JS:

```
let errMsg = 'Error Message: ' + error.body.message + '\n';
errMsg = errMsg + 'Stacktrace: ' +  error.body.stackTrace;
```

In HTML:

```
<lightning-formatted-text value={errorMessage} linkify ></lightning-formatted-text>
```

Comment: How is the tag showing the text without binding? Also how is it used in a toast?

Comment: This isn't for a toast message, but if you want to display a String with a line break in LWC, it works.  In your js file, you have a variable:

@track errorMessage

In your js code, you can assign the value:

this.errorMessage='Hello\nWorld'

Use the lightning-formatted-text tag as shown above to display text with a line break.

Answer (score -2):

Use javascript backticks

```
 showToast() {
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Get Help',
            message: `Salesforce documentation is available in the app.
 Click ? in the upper-right corner.`,
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: No luck.. still displaying in one line..

Comment: Currently, it's not possible. Shall I create a custom component for you?

Comment: i have a custom component...i was wandering will it be possible in standard way..thank u nikhil..