# How to display toast message in multiple lines using LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I need to show toast message in separate lines using LWC.
Like this,
[image]

I tried with '\n' and 'br' tag but it is not working.

```
<div>
    <lightning-button label="Toast Msg" variant="brand-outline" onclick={handleToastMsg} style="margin-left: 10px;"></lightning-button>
</div>

handleToastMsg(){
    var value = 'First Message \n';
    value += 'Second Message';

    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Toast Success',
        message: value,
        variant: 'success',
        mode: 'dismissable'
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

can anyone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [line break in lwc](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/304922/line-break-in-lwc)

Comment: Looks like it's not possible in LWC though someone may have found a solution since that question was asked

Comment: From the ideas exchange: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdkhjUAB/showtoastevent-message-display-in-multiple-line-lwc

Comment: Have you checked this?  [Multiple Lines Toast in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278366/how-to-show-toast-message-in-multiple-lines-in-a-lightning-web-component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to override the CSS to show the toast message in separate lines.

- First, you must create one static resource file as mentioned below for the CSS.
- Static Resource(public):

toastCSS.css

```
.toastMessage {
        white-space: break-spaces !important;
}
```

[image]

- After that use this static resource in your LWC component.

HTML:

```
<template>
        <div>
                <lightning-button label="Toast Msg" variant="brand-outline" onclick={handleToastMsg} style="margin-left: 10px;">
                </lightning-button>
        </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import customCSS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/toastCSS';
export default class DataBinding extends LightningElement {
    
    @track isCSSLoaded = false;

    renderedCallback() {

        if (this.isCSSLoaded) return;
        this.isCSSLoaded = true;
        loadStyle(this, customCSS).then(() => {
            console.log('css loaded successfully');
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('error to load css');
        });
    }


    handleToastMsg() {
        var msg = 'First Message\nSecond Message\nThird Message';

        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Toast Success',
            message: msg,
            variant: 'success',
            mode: 'dismissable'
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it is working

Answer (score 1):

Inserting line breaks is not supported. Ideally, the message conveyed in toast is succinct enough to be captured in one or two sentences. If you are trying to display more information, perhaps another [notification](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/guidelines/notifications/overview/) mechanism would be better suited for the task.

That being said, LDS design guidance suggests patterns to [condense text](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/guidelines/messaging/components/toasts/#flavor-ui-text) in situations where you might be listing users, contacts, etc.